# jQuery each(); generating html elements returns only last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to dynamically populate HTML from XML data. I need only certain values. I managed to do it with each(); and everything outputs perfectly when I console log it, but when I try to generate HTML code for each object I get only data from last one (only 1 div is generated).

Here is example code:

**XML:**

```
<sms protocol="0" address="+00000000000" date="1514988026768" type="2" subject="null" body="Some text...1" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="3 Jan 2018 15:00:26" contact_name="Name1" />
<sms protocol="0" address="+00000000000" date="1514988062956" type="1" subject="null" body="Some text...2" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+00000000" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1514988062000" readable_date="3 Jan 2018 15:01:02" contact_name="Name1" />
<sms protocol="0" address="+00000000000" date="1515074431967" type="1" subject="null" body="Some text...3" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+000000000" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1515074430000" readable_date="4 Jan 2018 15:00:31" contact_name="Name1" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "sms" ).each(function(index, value){
if ($(this).attr("type") == 1) {
    sender = "name1";
    divClass = "class1";
    pClass = "pclass1";
}else if ($(this).attr("type") == 2) {
    sender = "name2";
    divClass = "class2";
    pClass = "pclass2";
}
text = $(this).attr("body");
date = $(this).attr("readable_date");

$('.mainwrap').html(
$('<div class="'+divClass+'"><p class="senderName">'+sender+'</p><p class="'+pClass+'">'+text+'</p><p class="dates">'+date+'</p>    </div>'));
   });
 });
```

With this code, I get only 1 div generated "Some text...3" (from XML).
Console log outputs values from all 3 properly.

From reading on other sources I guess I messed up at HTML generating part since it will generate only with data from the last iteration, but I'm fairly new to this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Giacomo Cosimato said, you are erasing the content each time by using `.html()` which **change** the content of the element, instead you need to use `.append()` which will **add** the content to the element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("sms").each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).attr("type") == 1) {
      sender = "name1";
      divClass = "class1";
      pClass = "pclass1";
    } else if ($(this).attr("type") == 2) {
      sender = "name2";
      divClass = "class2";
      pClass = "pclass2";
    }
    text = $(this).attr("body");
    date = $(this).attr("readable_date");

    $('.mainwrap').append(
      $('<div class="' + divClass + '"><p class="senderName">' + sender + '</p><p class="' + pClass + '">' + text + '</p><p class="dates">' + date + '</p>    </div>'));
  });
});
```

```css
.mainwrap {
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sms protocol="0" address="+00000000000" date="1514988026768" type="2" subject="null" body="Some text...1" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="3 Jan 2018 15:00:26" contact_name="Name1"
/>
<sms protocol="0" address="+00000000000" date="1514988062956" type="1" subject="null" body="Some text...2" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+00000000" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1514988062000" readable_date="3 Jan 2018 15:01:02"
  contact_name="Name1" />
<sms protocol="0" address="+00000000000" date="1515074431967" type="1" subject="null" body="Some text...3" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+000000000" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1515074430000" readable_date="4 Jan 2018 15:00:31"
  contact_name="Name1" />
  
  <div class="mainwrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using jQuery from awhile now, but it seems that you're replacing the HTML in the wrapper every time, instead of of appending the new div